# MySql - Find values that occur EXACTLY two times without using aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

### Table:**City**

```
City_Name (PK)    State_Name (PK)    Population
--------------    ---------------    ----------
Austin            MA
Austin            TX
Burlington        VT
Fresno            CA
Houston           TX
Independence      KS
Independence      MO
Independence      PA 
Kansas            CA 
Kansas            MO
Paris             MO 
Paris             OR 
Paris             TX 
Paris             VA  
Paso              TX
```

The above table has a composite primary key (City_Name and State_Name). I want to **find the city which occur in exactly two distinct States**(no more, no less). In this case, the result will be

```
City_Name
---------
Austin
Kansas
```

Other cities will not qualify as they occur in one or more than two states.This solution is required for practicing relational calculus problems and thus (unfortunately) **any aggregate function such as COUNT() cannot be used.**

Looking forward to hearing from some kind-hearted people.

NB - Not finding any clue where to start from, thus no effort could be shown :(

Comment: We're not doing your homework. You have to provide some SQL queries you tried.

Comment: @MrTux Not finding any clue where to start from, thus no effort could be shown..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct c1.city_name
from city c1
  join city c2 
    on c2.city_name = c1.city_name 
   and c1.state_name <> c2.state_name
where not exists (select 1
                from city c3
                where c3.city_name = c1.city_name 
                  and c3.state_name not in (c1.state_name, c2.state_name));
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d0901/8

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if mysql does not support minus/except:

```
-- two or more states 
select c1.city_name 
from city c1 
join city c2 
    on c1.city_name = c2.city_name 
   and c1.state_name<>c2.state_name 
minus
-- three or more states
select c1.city_name 
from city c1 join city c2 
    on c1.city_name = c2.city_name 
   and c1.state_name<>c2.state_name 
join city c3 
    on c1.city_name = c3.city_name 
   and c1.state_name <> c3.state_name 
   and c2.state_name <> c3.state_name;
```

rewriting using not in:

```
-- two or more states
select distinct c1.city_name 
from city c1 
join city c2 
    on c1.city_name = c2.city_name 
   and c1.state_name<>c2.state_name 
where c1.city_name not in (
    -- three or more states
    select c1.city_name 
    from city c1 
    join city c2 
        on c1.city_name = c2.city_name 
       and c1.state_name<>c2.state_name 
    join city c3 
        on c1.city_name = c3.city_name 
        and c1.state_name <> c3.state_name 
        and c2.state_name <> c3.state_name
);
```

Answer (score 2):

@a_horse_with_no_name's answer is a perfectly good (and straightforward) solution. Below is another way of accomplishing the same thing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.city_name
FROM   city c1
       JOIN city c2
          ON c2.city_name = c1.city_name AND c1.state_name <> c2.state_name
       LEFT JOIN city c3
          ON     c1.city_name = c3.city_name
             AND c3.state_name NOT IN (c1.state_name, c2.state_name)
WHERE  c3.city_name IS NULL
```

This solution creates a sets of 2-3 cities in the `FROM` clause, then weeds out the ones that have a third city using the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

So this query will count the number of duplicated rows and will remove those that have a higher count than 2 and those with a lower count of 2. try it out! :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_name 
FROM city
WHERE city_name NOT IN
(   SELECT IF(counting_col > 2, city_name, NULL) AS city_name_s 
    FROM
    (   SELECT city_name, IF(@A = city_name, @B := @B + 1, @B := 1) AS counting_col, @A := city_name
    FROM city
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A := '', @B := 1) t
    ORDER BY city_name
    ) t1
    HAVING city_name_s IS NOT NULL
)
AND city_name IN
(   SELECT IF(counting_col = 2, city_name, NULL) AS city_name_s 
    FROM
    (   SELECT city_name, IF(@A = city_name, @B := @B + 1, @B := 1) AS counting_col, @A := city_name
    FROM city
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A := '', @B := 1) t
    ORDER BY city_name
    ) t1    
    HAVING city_name_s IS NOT NULL
)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c1f8/10)

Comment: is it where counting_col = 2, or having count_col = 2?  Like the solution...curious if it works.

Comment: Although this is a clever answer that yields the correct result (using MySQL user variables), I don't believe it's a good fit for the goal of the exercise: _practicing relational calculus_ - the idea is to solve the problem without counting.

Comment: @jpw sorry I thought the OP wanted a counting way to do it :/

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you very much for your effort, but it looks little bit complicated for a noob like me, couldnt yet grab CROSS JOIN and IFs in SQL..

Comment: cross join is another way to join.. i just use it so you can differentiate between which joins are being used for creating the variable... IF statements are pretty simple too :) IF(condition, when true, when false). Just as an fyi for future reference :)